# What C++ math libraries are typically used by quants?

Tags: programming

Before you mark question as off-topic, please read it - it *is*, actually, quant-related.

Basically, I'm working on an app that spits out a lot of C++ math. When it comes to simple things like exponents and trig, I can use an STL function. But when it comes to things like matrix operations or normal distributions or anything else that's not part of the STL, I'm not quite sure which library to support.

That's the reason for this question - I'd like to know what kind of C++ libs quants typically use (in addition to the STL and such) most. My idea is to support those which are the most common. (I'm thinking of things like BLAS, MKL, Boost.Math, etc.)

BTW, if anyone's interested, [here's an overview](http://vimeo.com/34905137) of what I'm building.

Comment: Looks interesting!

Comment: Hello Dmitri, this question most likely receives a decent amount of traffic and activity on this site and the link towards the end of your question seems to be broken. If that is purposeful, in that you removed it because it has sensitive information then it would be useful to delete that line altogether. However if this is not the case, fixing the link would be beneficial!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For linear algebra etc, I am partial to [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) with [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) as an alternative. Both are modern (eg templated), actively developed and fairly high-performance.

I like my C++ together with R and stand behind a few projects like [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) and [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which facilitate that integration; 
[RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) then brings [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) to R.

For quant stuff, there is of course [QuantLib](http://www.quantlib.org) and my (too slow-moving :-/) [RQuantLib](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html).

Comment: Hey Dirk, I thought R already used BLAS. If so, what does Armadillo add for an R user?

Comment: It helps to look at it the other way: RcppArmadillo helps you to write simple C++ linear algebra, almost Matlab style, that is C++ fast.  At run-time, it will indeed refer to whichever BLAS R uses, which may well be optimised, multicore, ... such as Goto or MKL.  Makes sense?  So the point is when you need to code something that R doesn't yet do, or does too slowly, the RcppArmadillo integration makes it pretty easy to get the job done.

Comment: So, you're just advocating C++ over R, eh? ;)

Comment: Nope, I advocate using C++ and R. A happy marriage. ;-)

Comment: So I should be targeting R then, too? Just how popular is it?

Comment: Just produce a clean and useful API, bindings to other systems will then come easily---using e.g. Rcpp.  And yes, if you do anything data releated (eg analysis, modeling, visualization, ...) then R is rather popular.

Comment: @Dirk: it's not so much the API I'm producing, rather it's the final calculations. So my query is, when I generate the calcuations, which libraries is it OK to target? So far I understand that Boost is one of those I can use.

Comment: I have worked with C++ for twenty years and your statement still makes no sense to me.  Why don't you focus on *release early, release often* and feedback on actual code?

Comment: @Dirk: that's what I'll do anyway, but I need to make sure the libs I support aren't forcing people to use anything they particularly dislike.

Comment: So you mean what other libraries you think you can use without putting up extra barriers to use and adoption?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel exactly!

Comment: @Dirk, this may be a bit off topic perhaps, but RQuantlib really needs to be able to support vector arguments already. For example, only being able to price American options through loops (as one can only pass scalars to the function) is brutal. Anyway, thanks for the package! Best Regards, VC

Answer (score 11):

What I use in my job:

- boost (the mathematical part)
- Eigen
- gsl
- glpk

and some scary legacy code ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The [NAG](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/CL/cldescription.asp) library is quite commonly used

Answer (score 5):

For many numerical procedures you can link against [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) libraries if Octave is installed.

Comment: While technically true, you should keep in mind that Octave is written to support its interpreter, not provide an API. Hence little use of *Octave as a library* in the sense of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the Intel math libraries.

See: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl

Comment: Could you please provide some links to enhance a bit the content of your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add one more library that may be of interest: http://www.yeppp.info/. It's not strictly a quant library but a:

> "SIMD-optimized mathematical library for x86, ARM, and MIPS processors
>   on Windows, Android, Mac OS X, and GNU/Linux systems."

Answer (score 2):

On my capstone project on Extreme Value Theory, LMM and Swap Pricing I used [dlib](http://www.dlib.net) . It has a lot of various mathematical capabilities. My use focused on vector and optimization calculations.